# Trying to get a quotient as a numeric object in R

Tags: r, string, console, user-input, numeric

I'd like to know if there is a simple way to get a user input such as "1/4" into a numeric object.

For example, I'd like to get something as the following:

```
> x <- as.numeric(readline("1/4"))
> print(x)
[1] 0.25
```

Of course, I will actually get this once I try to print `x`:

```
> print(x)
[1] NA
```

So, is there any easy way for R to understand that the user input is a quotient?

Also, I have the same question for other expressions such as "1*10^3" or "1e3".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for `eval(parse())`?

```
x <- "1/4"
eval(parse(text=x))
## 0.25

y <- "1*10^3"
eval(parse(text=y))
## [1] 1000

z <- "1e3"
eval(parse(text=z))
## [1] 1000
```